# Problems Adding Custom Class Library (dll) to Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, visual-studio-express

I've created a class library in C# Visual Express 2010. I built the solution making sure that the target framework was the `.NET Framework 4` **and not** `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`.

When I try to create a Console Application and reference the library, none of my classes are recognized.

1. I have made sure the Console Application is also using the `.NET Framework 4` **and not** `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`
2. I have made sure that I am actually `using` the namespace of my library.
3. All the classes I want to access are public.
4. If I change my `Class Library` project to a `Console Application` project, everything works.
5. Restarting and/or reloading the library does not work.
6. After I reference my library, it appears under `References`, but I cannot view it in the object viewer. I'm not sure what this means

The only error messages I receive are:
`Error  2   The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I'm not sure why nothing is recognized, or why I cannot use my library. Does anyone have any ideas of where I can go to look for the solution, or has anyone run into this problem themselves?

Comment: Are the classes in your library public?

Comment: @Saruman Yes, all the classes I want to access are public.

Comment: can you find the assembly and classes in view\object browser

Comment: @Saruman No. If I look into the object browser, I cannot see my library. I'm not sure what that means though.

Comment: perhaps check your project dependencies. You probably need to build the class library first then run your console app.

Comment: also remember to add your class library project reference into your console app.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @woodykiddy I already built the library, and I am able to browse and add the dll to my console app. Or are you suggesting I do something else?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks. I'll keep that in mind for future posts.

Comment: Perhaps just try unloading/reloading the project or restarting your VS and see if that helps? sometime it's the issue with VS iteslf

Comment: @woodykiddy Unfortunately, I've tried that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have tried a lot of things here, but ultimately the following should work

1. In your solution make sure you have your class library and your console app (Although you don't need to have the class library in the solution, this is just for sanity sake)
2. Make sure they are the same framework
3. Make sure they both compile, take note of any errors or warnings
4. Add a reference to your library (remove any previous references),i.e click your console app, click Add\Reference, click solution, then check your library, click add
5. Add the `using` statement to your console app
6. Just to make sure everything is good , do a Clean, and rebuild

if you have done all the above and its still not working, then this seems like a benign error
I.e if everything compiles, and there are no warnings, there is really no normal reason why this shouldn't just work

Comment: For me, the "Make sure they are the same framework" was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

All of classes that defines in class library must have -public- access modifier, unless these assemblies don't work!

Comment: Please read the question and its comments before posting. The original poster states, in response to the first comment, _"Yes, all the classes I want to access are public"_.